# inserting a list as a column in dataframe at specific location depending on value in row

Tags: python, pandas, list, statsmodels

so I have a dataframe (tsv/csv file), using numpy, pandas and statsmodels.

In one column "medianame" the name of the media (a stimulus) will appear on screen (this stimulus is moving. Each row represents a timestamp).

Whenever a specific media name appears in this column (for this example, let's say "stimulus1"), it is time to **inset a list** of lets say 5 numbers in another column, starting from this row on.

The other items in the column need to be empty (np.nan).

Another requirement is that it has to be inserted in every occasion the name appears "again" in the "medianame" column. So, it is possible that the number of items in the list is shorter than the number of consecutive occurrences of the medianame (see first occasion in the example below).

If the number of items in the list is longer than the number of consecutive occurrences of the medianame, it has to be cut off early (see second occasion in the example below).

Example:

```
List1 = [5, 7, 1, 8, 9] # to be inserted in column "position"
                        # when medianame "stimulus1" appears in column "medianame"

medianame
stimulus0
stimulus0
stimulus0
stimulus0
stimulus0
stimulus0
NaN
stimulus1
stimulus1
stimulus1
stimulus1
stimulus1
stimulus1
stimulus1
stimulus1
stimulus1
stimulus1
NaN
stimulus2
stimulus2
stimulus2
stimulus2
stimulus2
NaN
stimulus1
stimulus1
stimulus1
```

After appending at the right place, hopefully it will look like:

```
medianame     position
stimulus0     NaN
stimulus0     NaN
stimulus0     NaN
stimulus0     NaN
stimulus0     NaN
stimulus0     NaN
NaN           NaN
stimulus1     5
stimulus1     7
stimulus1     1
stimulus1     8
stimulus1     9
stimulus1     NaN
stimulus1     NaN
stimulus1     NaN
stimulus1     NaN
stimulus1     NaN
NaN           NaN
stimulus2     NaN
stimulus2     NaN
stimulus2     NaN
stimulus2     NaN
stimulus2     NaN
NaN           NaN
stimulus1     5
stimulus1     7
stimulus1     1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way using `merge` with `groupby`, `cumsum` and pd.Series constructor:

```
df.assign(key = df.groupby((df['medianame'] != 'stimulus1').cumsum()).cumcount())\
  .merge(pd.Series(List1, index=range(1,len(List1)+1)).rename('position'), 
         left_on='key', 
         right_index=True, 
         how='left')\
  .drop('key', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    medianame  position
0   stimulus0       NaN
1   stimulus0       NaN
2   stimulus0       NaN
3   stimulus0       NaN
4   stimulus0       NaN
5   stimulus0       NaN
6         NaN       NaN
7   stimulus1       5.0
8   stimulus1       7.0
9   stimulus1       1.0
10  stimulus1       8.0
11  stimulus1       9.0
12  stimulus1       NaN
13  stimulus1       NaN
14  stimulus1       NaN
15  stimulus1       NaN
16  stimulus1       NaN
17        NaN       NaN
18  stimulus2       NaN
19  stimulus2       NaN
20  stimulus2       NaN
21  stimulus2       NaN
22  stimulus2       NaN
23        NaN       NaN
24  stimulus1       5.0
25  stimulus1       7.0
26  stimulus1       1.0
```

#### Details

Create a series, s with the index range starting at 1:

```
s = pd.Series(List1, index=range(1,len(List1)+1)).rename('position')
```

Output:

```
1    5
2    7
3    1
4    8
5    9
Name: position, dtype: int64
```

Now, let's join that series to the dataframe df where stimulus1, but first we need to create a join key on df.

```
df_key = df.assign(key = df.groupby((df['medianame'] != 'stimulus1').cumsum()).cumcount())
```

Output:

```
    medianame  key
0   stimulus0    0
1   stimulus0    0
2   stimulus0    0
3   stimulus0    0
4   stimulus0    0
5   stimulus0    0
6         NaN    0
7   stimulus1    1
8   stimulus1    2
9   stimulus1    3
10  stimulus1    4
11  stimulus1    5
12  stimulus1    6
13  stimulus1    7
14  stimulus1    8
15  stimulus1    9
16  stimulus1   10
17        NaN    0
18  stimulus2    0
19  stimulus2    0
20  stimulus2    0
21  stimulus2    0
22  stimulus2    0
23        NaN    0
24  stimulus1    1
25  stimulus1    2
26  stimulus1    3
```

​Lastly, merge the df_key with s how='left' on key and s.index:

```
df_key.merge(s, how='left', left_on='key', right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
    medianame  key  position
0   stimulus0    0       NaN
1   stimulus0    0       NaN
2   stimulus0    0       NaN
3   stimulus0    0       NaN
4   stimulus0    0       NaN
5   stimulus0    0       NaN
6         NaN    0       NaN
7   stimulus1    1       5.0
8   stimulus1    2       7.0
9   stimulus1    3       1.0
10  stimulus1    4       8.0
11  stimulus1    5       9.0
12  stimulus1    6       NaN
13  stimulus1    7       NaN
14  stimulus1    8       NaN
15  stimulus1    9       NaN
16  stimulus1   10       NaN
17        NaN    0       NaN
18  stimulus2    0       NaN
19  stimulus2    0       NaN
20  stimulus2    0       NaN
21  stimulus2    0       NaN
22  stimulus2    0       NaN
23        NaN    0       NaN
24  stimulus1    1       5.0
25  stimulus1    2       7.0
26  stimulus1    3       1.0
```

And, if desired you can drop that key column.